# What is the type of a generic if not specified?

Tags: java, generics

If there is a class such as:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    T t;
}
```

and you instantiate it simply as `Foo foo = new Foo();` you will only get a warning. If there is no specification of what the type is, what is the type? Object? I cannot seem to find the answer.

As an extension of this question, if I had class like so:

```
public final class SomeClass{

    private SomeClass(){

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static void bar(Foo foo){

    }
}
```

It gives a warning on line `public static void bar(Foo foo)` because the generic is not specified. I cannot specify the generic without getting the generic... so how would I do the equivalent of `public static void bar(Foo<t> foo)` via getting the generic of foo. And no I cannot put a generic in SomeClass and use that because it is static. It is necessary for this class to be static.

-Note this isn't me wondering **why** it should not be used. I am aware it should be used and it is only allowed to not because of backwards compatibility. This is a question on how it will be used **in this specific case**.